# Python function with loops

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and I am trying to have a multi-variable defined function loop over a pre-defined range. However, the loop never seems to continue through the full range. The desired output would be two lists: my defined range (in this case, 0 - 23) and the outputs of my called function.

```
max_t = 24
user_t = range(max_t)
user_qi = 500
user_b = 1.20
user_di = 0.70

def my_funct(t, qi, b, di):
    for t in range(max_t):    
        return qi/((1.0+b*di*t)**(1.0/b))

my_funct(user_t, user_qi, user_b, user_di)
```

Comment: `return` will immediately terminate the function; returning the first value calculated in your `for` loop. You should append values to a list inside the loop and return once the loop is completed. A slightly more advanced method would be to use `yield` instead of `return` to convert your function to a generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, when the program enters `my_funct` and executes this line :

```
return qi/((1.0+b*di*t)**(1.0/b))
```

program exits immediately because of `return`. Expected behaviour would be done using list. You can append values to it and return it. So implementation that would be:

```
max_t = 24
user_t = range(max_t)
user_qi = 500
user_b = 1.20
user_di = 0.70

def (t, qi, b, di):
    result = []
    for t in range(max_t):    
        result.append(qi/((1.0+b*di*t)**(1.0/b)))
    return result

r = my_funct(user_t, user_qi, user_b, user_di)
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is just running once since you're immediately returning from it.

```
result_list = []
range_list = [i for i in range(max_t)]

def my_funct(t, qi, b, di):
  for t in range(max_t):
     result_list.append(qi/... whatever calculation) 
  return (result_list, range_list)
```